# Satellite L750 Screen resolution problem

Tags: graphics, resolution

I am new in Ubuntu, I just replaced my windows 7 with it, but after installation I am stuck with a resolution of 1024x768 and I have tried most of the fixes I find here and this is my 3rd time reformatting my laptop due to fail attempts on getting my desired resolution which is 1368x768.

Can anyone help me?

My Graphics card is Geforce GMT 525

Answer (score 0):

The Built in Linux drivers for Geforce video cards while good are not perfect,
and that could be part of the problem.
However you "might" have an option to install the drivers from Nvidia.

Here is how you do it:

First I would do a full update for the system from the update manager, and reboot to enable any new kernel stuff that would be put on the system (this really might be all thats needed).

Next open the "Additional Drivers" application and let it look for any drivers that might work. If it finds any it will display a list. you simply click on the one you want and click the activate button. (On a side note, for me I normally avoid drivers marked "post release".) After it completes the install you will need to reboot.